# missing values,classification task

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I am using this dataset `breastcancer` from UCI but it contains missing values. Can anyone help me to fix it? I am new to ML and I don't know a lot about missing values techniques. Here is the link for dataset [cancerdata](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data).

I tried this code on R :

```
data <- read.csv('D:/cancer.csv', header=FALSE)  # Reading the data 

for(i in 1:ncol(data)) {
    data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

but it gives me an error (sorry it may be trivial but I am really pretty new
here is a screenshot of the

thank you for your time and consideration

[here is the output I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HMNj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the missForest package in R: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/missForest/missForest.pdf

It is really easy to use, fast and does a great job imputing categorical and numeric values.

For a quick tutorial, see here: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/

Edit:
You have total 16 missing values in the data, all in column 7 (`V7`). You can check this by

```
data <- read.csv('D:/cancer.csv', header=FALSE)  # Reading the data
sum(data == "?")
sum(data$V7 == "?")
```

Now, missForest will impute all in NAs in data, no matter where they are. If you want to retain some NAs, separate that data first.

To impute all NAs:

```
data[data == "?"] <- NA
library(missForest)
data <- missForest(data)$ximp
```

Now all the NAs have been imputed and replaced with some meaningful values. To verify this:

```
sum(is.na(data))
```

Use this data with imputed values.

Comment: dear @fzk thank you for your feedback, just because all examples generate the missing data by themselves I have tried this but I get an error can you help me to fix it please ,  does the data have to be in specific form the missing data in my case is "?" have I to change it in NA !   `    canccer <- read.table('D:/aa.txt', header = F)# Reading the 
               data 
               b <- missForest('D:/aa.txt')` the dataset I use is from here [link](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/breast-cancer-wisconsin.data)

Comment: Please try the code I have added and see if that works

Comment: It does not give me any error thank you ( I have this output missForest iteration 1 in progress...done! /2 iteration
here is the what I have tried                                                         'canccer <- read.table('D:/cancer.txt', header = F)# Reading the data 
canccer[canccer == "?"] <- NA   
library(missForest)
canccer.imputed <- missForest(canccer)$ximp'  am I supposed to change "data" by the name of my file is not it? and how to acced to the output with the data where missing input are imputed ! btw I just want the data completed am not going to do any calculation..

Comment: another question please am not supposed to tell this function misssforset in which attributes there is missing values is not it ? by writing the code you sent it just would replace all the "?" by values is not it ( soory because new on R also so really do not know..)

Comment: I have added a figure which include the output fzk there are till now "?" when I type "canccer.imputed " did I miss somthing !!

Comment: Run the code from the start and you will get the `data` with correct values. I would advise you to take a basic course in R for better understanding. Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you @fzk it works thank you yeah Iwill do for sure, it is the first time I use R thank you ( am not working with, It was just for dealing with missing data.. That s way I did know to fix it  and understand the syntax..) thank you again :) I have put it as the answer but soory I could not vote up it since I have not  yet voting privilege) thank you again